# Excel VBA - Allow input to cells with DisplayFormulaBar=False

Tags: vba, excel

OK it's taken me a while to figure this out and it is extremely annoying...

**Excel 2013 Pro Plus** *Fully patched to July 2014*

In my project I have

```
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
```

which works as expected, it hides the FormulaBar.  What is NOT expected is that it Stops the inputting of data into any cell.

I have to do a

```
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
```

to allow the inputting of data again which is inconsistent with the design of the application.

Does anyone know of anyway to hide the FormulaBar and still allow input into cells?

I'm using my own validation inside the VBA code to ensure right place and value...other cells are locked.

Many thanks in advance,
regards
Seán

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Press Alt+T+O
Advanced
Editing Options
Give a Tick Mark in Allow Editing Directly in Cells
```

[Source](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1020437-changing-application-displayformulabar-prevents-cell-edits.html) (scroll down)

Comment: Hi, and thanks for that.  Unfortunately I can get this to happen even with the tick mark in the _Allow Editing Directly in Cells_ box.  So it is definitely a problem in Excel and **.displayformulabar** as far as I can see.  I'll raise it through the Partners Technical area.  Marked as complete even though not ...regards Seán

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Program Manager on the Excel team, and I wanted to provide some input on a bug we discovered that seems related to what we are seeing. Specifically, in Excel 2013 and later, when the formula bar is disabled, you (1) call `DisplayAlerts = false` (2) from an ActiveX control, you will get into a state where you can no longer edit cells. You didn't mention conditions #1 and #2, but it seemed related, and it might be the same issue you are seeing.

We are fixing this particular issue in an upcoming update to Office365. If you get into this state, one way to work around it by setting `DisplayFormulaBar` to `true`, then back to false.